# list of English words to refer to humans

Tags: text, text-mining, nlp

I am trying to automatically process English sentences and detect the words which might be referring to humans. e.g. he, everybody, someone, niece, I, son, ...
I am already using NER, and have implemented some simple heuristic rules as well.
But I think, other than tricky cases which is fine if I mis-label them, the problem can be solved with a simple dictionary look-up. Is there any list of English words that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

found some lists on the web:

```
https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/words/family1.htm
https://www.really-learn-english.com/list-of-pronouns.html
https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/words/jobs1.htm
```